# Ошибка при создании virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Пытаюсь создать virtualenv для проекта на Django.
Среда разработки Windows10, Python 3.7. Возникает ошибка :
***UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 27: invalid continuation byte***
Я так понимаю надо исправить ошибку при чтении данной кодировки. Может кто сталкивался, подскажите.
[image: Скан экрана с ошибками]

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 712, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 947, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 904, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 772, in call_subprocess
    line = line.decode(fs_encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 27: invalid continuation byte
E:\Merged Volume'Local Volume'\Мои документы\Django\Django\Mysite\feedback\feedback\myproject>
```

Comment: текст лучше приводить в виде текста ([edit])

Comment: Вероятно, проблема в том, что у вас кириллические символы в путях.